# Custom class with sqlite3

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm new here, but I've been following you for a long time and I've taken inspiration from you many times to solve some problems.
Now I send you this new question: for a larger project I have to use the Sqlite3 library in C++ creating an object that is suitable for my needs.
Obviously I've searched a lot, but I can't find an answer to this question:
I'm trying to create a method that by passing by reference (pointer), is able to query a table and export the result in test format to the main function, with the "sqlite3_column_text()" function.
I can't get the expected result.
Maybe by posting some code I will be able to be clearer.

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class dbase
{
    public:
        dbase(const char* dbfile);
        void db_query(unsigned char** pas_t, char* sql);
        virtual ~dbase();

    private:
     sqlite3* db;
     sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
};

dbase::dbase(const char* dbfile)
{
   sqlite3_open(dbfile, &db);
}


void dbase::db_query(unsigned char** pas_t, char* sql){
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);
    int i = 0;
    const unsigned char** pr = new const unsigned char*[3];

    while ((sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            pr[i] = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
            pas_t[i] = (unsigned char*)pr[i];
            cout << "pas_t = " << pas_t[i] << "  " << endl;
        i++;
    } cout << "\nend\n" << endl;

}

dbase::~dbase()
{
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

int main() {
    dbase* db = new dbase("./Test.db");
    unsigned char** glb = new unsigned char*[4];
    db->db_query(glb, (char*)"SELECT Nome FROM Test");
   int n = 0;
   while(glb[n] != NULL){
        cout << "glb -- " << glb[n] << "--" << n << endl;
        n++;
    }

    delete glb;
    db->~dbase();
    return 0;
}
```

risultato:

```
pas_t = primo  
pas_t = secondo  
pas_t = terzo  

end

glb -- ���?V--0
glb -- ���?V--1
glb -- ���?V--2
```

the unsigned char** glb variable should have contained the three strings.

Comment: The pointer returned by `sqlite3_column_text` is only valid until the next `sqlite3_step` or `sqlite3_reset` or `sqlite3_finalize`. If you need the data it points to for longer, you have to allocate your own memory and copy it over.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.